# Domain doesn't work without `www`

Tags: .htaccess, web, dns, subdomain

When I type in my domain name like without the `www` (like `http://example.com`), it doesn't work and gives error message. However, when I add the `www` to it (like `http://www.example.com`), it works.

Isn't it supposed to work both ways (with and without the `www`)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

All you need is to add the following code to your root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: It would be nice if you explained to people what this actually does. Here's a blog using the same code http://dense13.com/blog/2008/02/27/redirecting-non-www-to-www-with-htaccess/

Comment: Thanks@trainoasis for the link. It should be self explanatory. it adds www to the domain and any subdomain or subfolders and so on...

Comment: You need to understand regular expressions to decipher the code. The second line means: if the HTTP_HOST does not (!) start with (^) "www.", then put it in memory for the next line.  The next line says: from what was captured in the previous line, match everything (.*) from beginning (^) to end ($) and save everything (inside the parenthesis) as $1. Then replace $1 with "http://www." plus the HTTP_HOST variable.

Comment: where to add these code tho? does it have to do with backend language?

Comment: you can add them to your .htaccess file in your main web server tree.

Comment: I tried using this code but it does not work for me. I get forbidden error when i try to access my website without www.

Answer (score 8):

With the current version of apache, you need to do the following, which has changed compared to the previous versions:

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-enabled
```

Now find the config file for your domain and edit it (the first three lines after `<VirtualHost *:80>` is what we need here):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.yourdomain.com
        ServerAlias yourdomain.com *.yourdomain.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

And now after saving changes to the file, you should reload Apache we server configuration with:

```
service apache2 reload
```

and it'll work!

P.S. You may also want not to add `*.yourdomain.com` to the end of your `ServerAlias` line.

Comment: `ServerAlias www.yourdomain.com yourdomain.com` works. Thanks.

Comment: @node_saini please upvote the answer if it helped you. :-)

Comment: Done :) But is this the right way to do it? It would not cause any problem right?

Comment: @node_saini yep! You upvote the questions and answers that you find helpful. So should do anyone else. :-)

Comment: It helped me no doubt but there is a right way and a wrong way to solve a problem and wrong way doesn't mean it won't work, it will work but it's not the right way. This was my only concern :)

Comment: @node_saini oh right, I get you now. I hadn't understood your question. I don't think there's anything wrong with this, it's been a while since I'd figured it out and applied it to my server and it's been working fine.

Answer (score 4):

to solve this issue

- suppose you want  `mysubdomain.domain1.com`
- goto your dns records settings in your web panel ( cpanel , vestapanel etc ) of `domain1.com`
- add there new `A record` with `ip` of your `domain1.com` and fill record/hostname field with `@`     // @ mean no **www**  if you want **www** too then add another new `A record` and replace `@` with **www**
- save it
- wait for dns changes to take place maybe take few hours

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could follow below steps which solves this problem, for sure, if you're using GoDaddy and google apps :

1. Go to Google Apps and sign in to domain management.
2. Then click on domain settings.
3. Then click on domain Names.
4. Then Click on words highlighted to set a redirect via google apps and you should see it done within 3 hours or MAX 2 DAYS (though it usually does not take more than a day in the rarest case).Just follow the simple english instructions there and you should see it done.

More details and reference :

http://www.techproceed.com/2014/05/custom-domain-setup-on-blogger-with.html

Answer (score -2):

You need to change any full urls to paths. If your php include or other processes are linked using urls, it will only work one way.

```
$.ajax(
{       
    url:'/LAYOUT/process.php'
}
```

as oppose to the full url

```
$.ajax(
{       
    url:'https://www.yourdomain.com/LAYOUT/process.php'
}
```

Using a simple path will allow it to work both ways with or without www.

Answer (score -2):

1st go your domain provider website.
2nd go dns record.
3rd add A record IP go this [link](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/1233387)

and copy 4A records and add dns.