# Resource loading failed with out www in url

Tags: javascript, html, css, dns, resources

In my html pages , I gave the resources links as

```
https://mydomain.com/sites/default/files/styles/sds.img
```

That resource is loading nicely when I hit the url in browser with below url,

```
www.mydoamin.com
```

But when I hit the url like below

```
mydomain.com
```

Surprisingly it is failed to load the resource. What could be the problem ??

And when I remove the https and converted to http like

```
http ://mydomain.com/sites/default/files/styles/sds.img
```

It's working again.

The resources I'm linking are images, javascripts and css. What exactly going on here. I don't have any clue.

Thanks for any inputs.

Comment: Can you access any part of the site without the www prefix? Is [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10135456/domain-without-www-not-working-but-with-www-is-working) of any help to you?

Comment: You might have installed your ssl certificate on the subdomain www....

Comment: @colonelsanders Yes. I'm seeing the image, if I access like `mywinners.com/sites/d.....`

Comment: @SimonPaquet's suggestion sounds likely. You could then modify your .htaccess to redirect everything to https://www

Comment: does your ressource headers returns a 404, a 500 ?

Comment: @SimonPaquet In my chrome console in status column ,it is showing like  (failed)
net::ERR_INSEC`

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ May I suggest using a client like Fiddler2 to debug as it works as a proxy for https requests (It's gonna tell you it's unsecured but you will have the headers) and try to reach the https ressource itself. I don't know how the chrome console works since I use firebug but there should be a response header with either a 200 404, 301, 500 code...

Comment: @SimonPaquet In firebug, the status is showing `Aborted`

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Well, you should do as colonelsanders wrote up there to make it work (if you are on Apache of course). I'm not a pro in SSL certificates but it looks like it's installed on www rather than on the domain itself...