# Domain doesn't work without `www`, what's the fix in node.js

Tags: node.js, http, redirect, web, https

I know this question has been asked
[Domain doesn't work without `www`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10135456/domain-doesnt-work-without-wwwemphasized)

But I need a solution for node.js app hosted on heroku and using namecheap with komodo

Also, I found this [similar thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17199095/nodejs-equivalent-of-this-htaccess) which i didnt' understand at all.

Can someone give an example of how to handle this in node.js?

Details: I'm using express. In Heroku I have

```
example.me(Domain Name)   yamanashi-3938.herokussl.com (DNS Target)

www.example.me(Domain Name)   yamanashi-3938.herokussl.com(DNS Target)
```

In Namecheap I have:

```
 @ | https://www.example.me | URL redirect 
www | yamanashi-3938.herokussl.com. | CNAME
```

Comment: Several questions.  Are you using Express in node.js?  Do you have a DNS record set up for your domain with the `www` on it?  If so, is that pointing to the same server.  And, do you want the site to just work without `www` or do you want it to redirect to the `www` URL (the redirect is generally considered better for SEO, I believe).

Comment: Not sure if what i did worked as you pointed out.. can you check again? I updated

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future, please ask questions like this there.

Comment: sure thing. why don't you guys come up with a 'question migration button' for those in the wrong bucket? seems some are quite focused on this issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`www.example.com` and `example.com` are different records in the DNS. You need to make sure both are pointing to the same place. You can either set both to point to the same address or setup the `example.com` to redirect to the `www.example.com`.

If you're using namecheap it should look something like this.

```
+------------+---------------------------+--------------+
| Host Name  |      IP Address/URL       | Record Type  |
+------------+---------------------------+--------------+
| @          | http://www.yourdomain.com | URL Redirect |
| www        | app-name.herokuapp.com.   | CNAME(Alias) |
+------------+---------------------------+--------------+
```

Make sure you also add the domain under your Heroku project settings.

Comment: @XiaoQu yeah, just make sure the url forwarding is to https

Comment: @XiaoQu I should be more clear. You can redirect from http:// -> https:// but not from https:// -/-> https:// (does that make sense?)